# run python code from android and return to android

Tags: java, android, python

hello currently am developing a app in pure native Android code.

but i came across a python script that would be very useful in my project. So i want to use this in my android code. My question is: is it possible to call this piece of python code from android and return the result that the python script has put out to my android environment?

PSEUDO PSUEDO CODE:

```
Python p = new Python();
String resultOfPythonScript = p.execute("somescript.py");
Log.d(TAG, resultOfPythonScript);
```

Comment: [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) may help.